# what does vector<int> dist(n, INT_MAX); mean in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor

i am new to C++ and I was wondering what the below code does. I tried googling but could not find the answer. Thanks

```
vector<int> dist(n, INT_MAX);
```

Comment: Creates a vector of size `n` and initialises each element to `INT_MAX`.

Comment: `std::vector` has a lot of different constructors, just browse cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: [check the list of constructors for `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), it's the 3rd type in the list. You should [read a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/995714) instead of seeing random code snippets or try random programming problems, that'll make your future questions be closed very quickly

Comment: You definitely should find reference material you are comfortable with so you can look this stuff up for yourself.

Comment: if `x` and `INT_MAX` are type here, it can also be a function declaration.

Comment: @ferocioussprouts122 Refer to a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), this is explained in any beginner level C++ book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code serves to declare a variable called `dist`, and to initialise it is a `std::vector` object.

The `<int>` part of the vector initialisation is called a template argument. The `std::vector` class is templated, which means it can store any arbitrary data-type, which is why the type has to be declared within angled brackets `<>`.

As mentioned in the comments, `n` and `INT_MAX` are values being passed to one of the constructors of the `std::vector`. It is only one of the constructors, since there are various different overloads of the constructor (check out the documentation in the comments to your question to read about the different available constructors).

Function (and also method) overloading is when you declare various functions with the same name, but that differ in the number and/or types of parameters that can be passed to them (the return type can also vary).

Comment: Pedantic point: the code **defines** a variable called `dist`. `vector<int>dist;`would **declare** it. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Vector is a container C++ has already prepared.

I guess u should read the manual of STL before u use the class in it. And next is the answer;

Vector just like a string,but it has built many useful functions in it which make programers more inclined to use.

`vector<int> dist(n, INT_MAX);` the template is `vector<type> name()`.

`(n, INT_MAX)` is initialization statement, it will put n INT_MAXs to the vector.

`INT_MAX` means largest number of type int;

If it helps you, please cast me a vote.

Comment: What's the point of defining a container in terms of another container, both of which are possibly unknown to the OP? Furthermore: You don't consider `std::string` to provide useful functions? The reason for using `std::vector` is that `std::string` is designed specifically to work with character sequences and `std::vector` is designed as as container for arbitrary element types.